# Problem running windows software on wine

Tags: wine

I installed a windows game successfully, however when I tried to run it, the software is asking me to insert the CD into the CD-ROM, which I did. But then after I press OK, nothing happen.

I'm guessing somehow game unable to access the CD-ROM. What do I need to do so I can get this game to work? FYI, when I insert a CD, the content of the CD automatically show up under /media/. There is a /cdrom/ folder, but it's empty.

Please help anyone?

Thanks

Comment: What software are you trying to install?

Comment: Wine isn't a complete windows emulator. Check if your program is supported! http://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: Have you tried using `PlayOnLinux` ? :)

Comment: It's unlikely to be a problem with not accessing the CD ROM. It sounds to me like the program crashes after you insert the CD and click okay. You may need to run it from a terminal and post the output. Most likely you are missing a dll. BTW what game is it that you are trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to install a locally made game for my children. It kinda worked by following the suggestion to use ISO instead of the actual CD-ROM, but it gave me a runtime error. I guess the program is not supported.

Comment: I'll give PlayOnLinux a go. Thanks all! Really appreciate all the help here

Answer (score 1):

1. [Create an ISO image from the CD](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-creating-cd-rom-iso-image.html).
2. [Configure Wine to see ISO as a CD drive.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9482021&postcount=10)
3. ???
4. Profit!

Comment: Thanks Greg, it worked, but it gave me a runtime error... oh well :(